# Is it possible to tell if the environment has been passed into a rake task block or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two simple rake tasks -- one that works and one that throws the following error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `my_config_param' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007ffba6b2d320>
```

Here are the tasks:

```
task :with_env => :environment do
  Rails.application.config.my_config_param #works
end

task :without_env do
  Rails.application.config.my_config_param #fails
end
```

It's pretty clear why `:without_env` fails and I can easily wrap my call to `Rails.application.config` in a begin/rescue statement. But I would like to know if there's a way I can tell *a priori* if the environment is missing so I can work around this more elegantly. Is there such a way? I've been unable to find one....

Comment: not sure about elegant, but would it be as simple as unless Rails.nil?

Comment: @mackmack `Rails.nil?` returns `false` in both of the above tasks, so no, I don't think I can use that.

Comment: @Beerlington Yes. In both of the above tasks, `Rails.env` returns `"development"` (or whatever environment was specified). This was one of the first things I tried and I found it surprising that *some* of the `Rails.*` calls still work even though mine did not....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague of mine noted that `$rails_rake_task` returns true if the rails env is loaded and false otherwise. This did the trick:

`Rails.application.config.my_config_param if $rails_rake_task`